# Can I pass the code reference of an object's method in Perl?

Tags: perl, methods, reference, closures

In a network handler dealing with various parameters to get and set I'm using closures heavily.
I have a subroutine that receives a closure and builds another closure using that passed as parameter on return (Sounds complicated, but that's just *why* I want such).
Now I have a case where I would have to pass two very similar closures, each using the same object method, but with different parameters (the object method checks the number of parameters passed).

My idea was not to pass two (or more) similar closures, but pass a reference `$meth_ref` to the object's method (the object is also passed to the function returning closures), so that the function can use the code reference to pass varying parameters.

Unfortunately I didn't find out the syntax to do so.

Code sketch:

```perl
sub closure_maker($$)
{
    my ($obj, $meth_ref) = @_;

    return sub (...) {
        $meth_ref->($obj);
        ...
        $meth_ref->($obj, ...);
    };
}

my @handlers = (closure_maker($obj1, ???), closure_maker($obj2, ???));
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: If you want method resolution, you can use `$ref = $obj->can('methodname')`

Comment: That does not help (in a way I can see it).

Comment: "_That does not help (in a way I can see it)_"  --- they meant, I think, that [UNIVERSAL::can](https://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL#$obj-%3Ecan(-METHOD-)) returns a code reference

Comment: You may be interested in the [curry](https://metacpan.org/pod/curry) module.

Comment: @zdim OK, I only had considered `->can()` in a Boolean context. My fault. So feel free to provide an answer using `can`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$obj->$method_name()`.

```perl
sub closure_maker($$)
{
    my ($obj, $method_name) = @_;

    return sub {
        $obj->$method_name();
        ...
        $obj->$method_name(...);
    };
}

my @handlers = map { closure_maker($_, "method_name") } $obj1, $obj2;
```

You can use `$obj->can` to obtain a reference to the method.

```perl
sub closure_maker($$)
{
    my ($obj, $method_name) = @_;

    my $method_ref = $obj->can($method_name);

    return sub {
        $obj->$method_ref();
        ...
        $obj->$method_ref(...);
    };
}
```

Comment: I guess it works, but it isn't getting the reference to the sub (method); instead it "searches" for the sub. So it's probably a bit less efficient.

Comment: It's no less efficient than doing `$obj->foo`... But updated to show how to use a reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to a method with `\&Classname::method` that can then be used with a given object of that class. For example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

package Example {
    sub new {
        my ($class, $name) = @_;
        return bless { name => $name }, $class;
    }

    sub method1 {
        my $self = shift;
        say "Method 1 of $self->{name}: @_";
    }
};

sub make_closure($$) {
    my ($obj, $method) = @_;
    return sub { $obj->$method(@_); }
}

my $obj1 = Example->new("Bob");
my $obj2 = Example->new("Cindy");
my $closure1 = make_closure($obj1, \&Example::method1);
my $closure2 = make_closure($obj2, \&Example::method1);
$closure1->(qw/1 2/);
$closure2->(qw/A B C/);
```

outputs

```
Method 1 of Bob: 1 2
Method 1 of Cindy: A B C
```

If you're paranoid, you might want to add type checking to the methods to make sure they're not accidentally called with an object of the wrong class. The `isa` operator, added in perl 5.32, makes this easy:

```perl
# In package Example
use Carp;
sub method1 {
    use experimental qw/isa/;
    my $self = shift;
    croak "Invalid object; should be an Example" unless $self isa Example;
    say "Method 1 of $self->{name}: @_";
}
```

Older versions can use the built-in `isa` method:

```perl
# In package Example
use Carp;
use Scalar::Util qw/blessed/;
sub method1 {
    my $self = shift;
    croak "Invalid object; should be an Example"
        unless defined blessed $self && $self->isa("Example");
    say "Method 1 of $self->{name}: @_";
}
```

Comment: You want `Example->can('method1')`, not `\&Example::method1` as the former ignores inherited methods (and can even create ghost methods breaking the object). But why not just pass `"method1"`?

Comment: Sorry, it's the *latter* (`\&Example::method1`) that ignores inherited methods.

Comment: What I don't like in this solution is the fact that even after creating the objects ($obj1, obj2) you have to know the (static) classes of the objects when calling `make_closure`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is really ugly, but it works.
The sample session is from the real code:

```perl
### this is the sample method:
  DB<5> x MessageLogFormat::log_appname($log_format)
0  ''
  DB<11> $xxxx = \&{*{MessageLogFormat::log_appname}}

  DB<12> x ref $xxxx
0  'CODE'
  DB<13> x $xxxx->($log_format)
0  ''
  DB<14> x $xxxx->($log_format, 1)
0  1
### NAME() just outputs the name of the class
  DB<17> $n = $log_format->NAME()
  DB<19> $xxx = \&{*{${n}.'::log_appname'}}
### the method is actually a closure (provided by class `Class`) by itself
  DB<20> x $xxx
0  CODE(0x1af8960)
   -> &Class::__ANON__[lib/Class.pm:85] in lib/Class.pm:78-85
  DB<21> x $xxx->($log_format)
0  1
  DB<22> x $xxx->($log_format, 0)
0  ''
  DB<23> x $xxx->($log_format)
0  ''
### So that worked; try a non-closure method, too:
  DB<24> $xxx = \&{*{${n}.'::new'}}
  DB<25> x $xxx
0  CODE(0x1afcb88)
   -> &MessageLogFormat::new in lib/MessageLogFormat.pm:85-91
```

In the solution sketched I don't have to know (and write down explicitly) the class of each object being used.

Comment: `\&{*{MessageLogFormat::log_appname}}` is a complicated way of writing `\&MessageLogFormat::log_appname`. But you should be using `MessageLogFormat->can('log_appname')` to honour inheritance. But it's a whole lot simpler to simply use the method name.